# Concept of xml sitemaps

Tags: xml, web, sitemap

I read pretty much about xml sitemaps and how they help search engines to crawl web pages. I believe the sitemap helps that website get into search results of google more often. But what I fail to understand is how a url would give all the required infor mation.
For example, We have a large website where used cars are sold in auctions. Here is an example url from our website.. **https://www.xxxxxxx.com/Vehicles/VehicleDetails.aspx?auctionID=945&itemID=1014.**

The above url does not give any information about the car itself. It just tells the auction id and stock number. **How does this url help a search engine???**

Please someone enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Site maps have two interesting properties:

- They contain the "last modification date" of pages. If you're using a site map that Google polls regularly, your changes will be taken into account fairly fast. Otherwise, you have to wait for Google to scan that specific page, which might take a while.
- They're basically a list of links to all the relevant pages in your site. This helps Google find all the pages without having to actually crawl through all the links, and also helps the spider find pages that are otherwise not linked to from anywhere in the site (but might be linked to from other sites).

Comment: Great! So how is the crawling done for very frequently changing websites? Should we submit the sitemap to google everytime website content changes? or just update the xml sitemap file sitting in the root folder of that website?